# How do you prevent a multi stage pipeline from being launched when another pipeline is running

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

I have a problem with multi stage pipelines. Let's say I have pipeline A and pipeline B.

Pipeline A is as follows :

- Stage A.1
- Stage A.2

Pipeline B is as follows :

- Stage B.1
- Stage B.2

Those pipelines work on different triggers placed on different repositories.

Sometimes we have the following behavior :

- Pipeline A starts stage A.1
- Then, before Pipeline A can begin stage A.2, Pipeline B ls launched because of its trigger and  starts stage B.1 (please note that pipeline A and B are totally independent one from another)
- Only after B.1 has finished, Pipeline A can continue on A.2

I don't complain about the sequential behavior, I don't want parallel runs. But I would like to tell to Azure DevOps to finish a pipeline before it starts another.

To summarize it all, can you tell Azure DevOps to finish a multi stage pipeline before it starts another pipeline ? And I'm not talking about another instance of the same pipeline, I am talking about a completely different pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a use case for exclusive locks. You could make an environment (environment A and environment B) in Azure pipelines for each of the pipelines and then apply an exclusive lock policy on these two environments. So you apply the *same* lock to both of the environments, not two separate locks.

For more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#exclusive-deployment-lock-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#exclusive-lock

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that's not what I want. First, we don't use environments and even if we did, I don't want a pipeline to Environment B to start if another pipeline to environment A is not finished.

Comment: @Laurent I meant applying the same lock to both of the environments, not two separate locks.

Comment: It is easy to set up and target an environment in Azure DevOps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops

Comment: OK I have created two environments and have added locks to both environment. There does not seem to be an option to reuse the same lock for two environments. Each environment seem to have its own lock.

Environments look useful when you deploy something. My pipelines are not always deploying anything.

I can't believe there is no option to tell Azure to finish a pipeline before beginning another. Even this default behavior looks like a bug to me.